# iPhone display date picker on UITextField touch

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uitextfield, protocols

I followed this thread: [datepicker by clicking on textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308754/datepicker-by-clicking-on-textfield)

I imported both of the following protocols:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

Then, in the implementation, I use the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    textField.delegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad] }
```

Lastly, I put the actual code to display the date picker (from the thread).  I also linked it all up in the IB.

```
    //Date Picker
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField{    
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];  

    pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];  

    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];  
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;  
    pickerView.hidden = NO;  
    pickerView.date = [NSDate date];  

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];  
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;  
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];  

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];  
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];  

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];  
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];  

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];  
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];  

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];  

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];  
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];  
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];  
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];    
}  

-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{  
    //Do something here here with the value selected using [pickerView date] to get that value  
        [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];  
}  

-(void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender{  
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];  
}
```

However, when I click on the UITextField, I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for fun, try putting the "[super viewDidLoad]" line before the "textField.delegate = self;" line in your viewDidLoad method!

Comment: I tried that just now.  Same result :(

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You could use the `UITextField` input view property. Just alloc init a regular `UIDatePicker` in code and assign it to the textfield's inputView. Doing this, the `UIPickerView` will be presented instead of the keyboard. If you need any code feel free to ask :)

EDIT: code

You fist hook up your `textField` with IB

```
@interface myViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
@end
```

In the implementation

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
    [datePicker setPreferredDatePickerStyle:UIDatePickerStyleWheels];
}       
[self.myTextField setInputView:datePicker];
```

That will bring up a `UIDatePicker` when you tap on the `textField`. Note the action that I added to the datePicker.

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

To update the textField each time that the user scrolls in the picker, you just need to implement the `updateTextField` method somewhere in the `viewController`

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
  UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.myTextField.inputView;
  self.myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
```

With this last method, every time the user rotates the picker, the textfield will update!

- You could use a `NSDateFormatter` to improve the output of the string.

Comment: I hate to be a hassle, but could you show some example of what you mean?  I don't follow :P  I'm pretty new to Iphone Development.

Comment: i've added you the code, if you need some further explanation just ask!

Comment: Where in the implementation do I put the UIDatePicker part of the code?

Comment: i'd put it in the viewDidLoad

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: "date picker is temporarily unavailable".

Comment: this could be to various reasons, one is memory leaks in your code. you might also be sending messages to a deallocated object, you can turn zombie objects to check that.

Comment: I had to specify window size and then it worked.  Thanks for all the help! :D

Comment: @tomi2711 i m new to iOS, i m getting error for [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date];

Comment: In that line of code you are missing a ] at the end. -> [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: And is there a way to dismiss keyboard when pressing out of the datapicker view?

Answer (score 12):

Below is how I am displaying the date picker.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


    self.activeTextField = textField;

    // Create a date picker for the date field.
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-31536000];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // If the date field has focus, display a date picker instead of keyboard.
    // Set the text to the date currently displayed by the picker.
    if (textField.tag == 1)
    {
    self.date.inputView = datePicker;
    self.date.text = [self formatDate:datePicker.date];
    }   
}


// Called when the date picker changes.
- (void)updateDateField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.date.inputView;
    self.date.text = [self formatDate:picker.date];
}


// Formats the date chosen with the date picker.
- (NSString *)formatDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM'/'dd'/'yyyy"];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I did in Swift 4:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setDatePicker()
}

func setDatePicker() {
    //Format Date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    //ToolBar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneDatePicker));
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));

    toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

    myTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    myTextField.inputView = datePicker
}

@objc func doneDatePicker(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    myTextField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

@objc func cancelDatePicker(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@JRo solution works great!

Here is my updated code in Swift 3:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.activeTextField = textField

    // Create a date picker for the date field.
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    picker.datePickerMode = .date
    picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateDateField(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)

    // If the date field has focus, display a date picker instead of keyboard.
    // Set the text to the date currently displayed by the picker.
    textField.inputView = picker
    textField.text = formatDateForDisplay(date: picker.date)
}


// Called when the date picker changes.

func updateDateField(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    activeTextField?.text = formatDateForDisplay(date: sender.date)
}


// Formats the date chosen with the date picker.

fileprivate func formatDateForDisplay(date: Date) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Comment: Great piece of code. In order to make it work in Swift4 just add `@objc` before the `func updateDateField`

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.2
You can achieve this by writing just one line of code using UITextField Extension.
**Credit:** http://www.swiftdevcenter.com/

```
import UIKit

extension UITextField {

    func setInputViewDatePicker(target: Any, selector: Selector) {
        // Create a UIDatePicker object and assign to inputView
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 216))//1
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date //2
        self.inputView = datePicker //3

        // Create a toolbar and assign it to inputAccessoryView
        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screenWidth, height: 44.0)) //4
        let flexible = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil) //5
        let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: nil, action: #selector(tapCancel)) // 6
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: target, action: selector) //7
        toolBar.setItems([cancel, flexible, barButton], animated: false) //8
        self.inputAccessoryView = toolBar //9

    }

    @objc func tapCancel() {
        self.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

In your UIViewController class write below code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.myTextField.setInputViewDatePicker(target: self, selector: #selector(tapDone(sender:datePicker1:))) //1
    }

    //2
    @objc func tapDone(sender: Any, datePicker1: UIDatePicker) {
        print(datePicker1)
        if let datePicker = self.myTextField.inputView as? UIDatePicker { // 2.1
            let dateformatter = DateFormatter() // 2.2
            dateformatter.dateStyle = .medium // 2.3
            self.myTextField.text = dateformatter.string(from: datePicker.date) //2.4
        }
        self.myTextField.resignFirstResponder() // 2.5
    }

}
```

**For more detail visit:** http://www.swiftdevcenter.com/uidatepicker-as-input-view-to-uitextfield-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this Process
In .h file create object for UIDatePicker

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker;
```

in .m file viewDidloadMethod

```
datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
[_dateTxtFld setInputView:datePicker];
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showSelectedDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *space=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space,doneBtn, nil]];

[_dateTxtFld setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];
```

after that you can create ShowSele

```
-(void)showSelectedDate {
    if ([_dateTxtFld isFirstResponder]) {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
        _dateTxtFld.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];
       [_dateTxtFld resignFirstResponder];
    }
   else if ([_timeTxtFld isFirstResponder]) {
   }
}
```

It's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach is to make your own class (I called it `TextFieldFormDate`) that is derived from `UITextField` and encapsulates all the required behaviour. In your storyboard you then set the class for the text field to `TextFieldFormDate` (in my case).

Use `didChange` and `didSelect` in your ViewController (that is using the `TextFieldFormDate`) to be notified of changes and when date is actually picked.

```
class TextFieldFormDate: UITextField {

    var date : Date {
        set {
           picker.date = newValue
           text = newValue.localizedDateOnly()
        }

        get {
            return picker.date
        }
    }

    //public handlers
    var didChange : ( (Date)->() )?
    var didSelect : ( (Date)->() )?

    private var picker : UIDatePicker {
        return inputView as! UIDatePicker
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        font = UIFont.defaultFont()
        //picker for datefield
        inputView = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        picker.datePickerMode = .date
        picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.tintColor = PaintCode.mainBlue
        toolBar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            BarBtnPaintCode(type: "done", target: self, action: #selector(didPressDone))
        ]
        toolBar.sizeToFit()
        inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }

    @objc private func pickerChanged() {
        text = date.localizedDateOnly()
        didChange?(picker.date)
    }

    @objc private func didPressDone() {
        text = date.localizedDateOnly()
        resignFirstResponder()
        didSelect?(picker.date)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Date Picker to UITextField as Input View - Swift Code. Hope it helps everyone. :)**

```
func addTimePickerToTimeTextFieldView() {

    timePicker = UIDatePicker()
    timePicker?.datePickerMode = .time
    timeTextField.inputView = timePicker

    timePicker?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    timePicker?.setValue(#colorLiteral(red: 0.03921568627, green: 0.2352941176, blue: 0.3647058824, alpha: 1), forKeyPath: "textColor")

    timePicker?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(timeSelectedByUser(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTapped(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

@objc func timeSelectedByUser(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    timeTextField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

    //Convert Time for API - 24 hours format
    apiFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    timeForApi = apiFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    func showDatePicker(){
    datepicker.datePickerMode = .date
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain , target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))
    let spaceBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
    toolBar.setItems([doneBtn,spaceBtn,cancelBtn], animated: false)
    dobTextfield.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    dobTextfield.inputView = datepicker
}
@objc func donedatePicker(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
    dobTextfield.text = formatter.string(from: datepicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
}
@objc func cancelDatePicker(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
```