# Simulating UIDatePicker date pick for testing

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

I'm using a combination of XCTest and OCMock for testing and I'd like simulate a user selecting a date from a UIDatePicker. Is there any way of doing this other than setting the date property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a UIDatePicker for selecting the date then The following tutorials will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11198489/2869784
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_the_iOS_7_UIPickerView_and_UIDatePicker_Components

Comment: I was looking for 'UIControlEventValueChanged' which was in the first link. Sending this to the datepicker I'm able to test it properly. Thanks.