# How to use one UIDatePicker to display only time on one button click and only date on another?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uidatepicker

Im working on an app where in a single view controller I have a date button and a time button. I want to put one date picker in the view. I want that single date picker to display only date on the date button click and only time on the time button click.
How is this possible?

Comment: First clear your question.

Comment: it is useful for you..



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197855/iphone-display-date-picker-on-textfield-click

Comment: I did edit the explanation. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set your mode using following property as per your requirement :

```
@property(nonatomic) UIDatePickerMode datePickerMode
```

Change your mode in your button actions appropriately.

For example, lets say you have `UIDatePicker *datePicker;`

you can set mode using below code :

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

There is one property in UIDatePicker:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIDatePickerMode datePickerMode;
```

Use this property to change picker type.

Picker type are as follows:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDatePickerMode) {
    UIDatePickerModeTime,           // Displays hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeDate,           // Displays month, day, and year depending on the locale setting (e.g. November | 15 | 2007)
    UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,    // Displays date, hour, minute, and optionally AM/PM designation depending on the locale setting (e.g. Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM)
    UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer, // Displays hour and minute (e.g. 1 | 53)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either of these approaches.

- If you are using Storyboard approach, you can simply set the mode to
  Time.
- If you are using the code based approach

`NSDatePicker *datePicker = [[NSDatePicker alloc] init];
 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
 ...`