# Display datepicker when tapping on UISearchController (Searchbar)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am using `UISearchController` programmatically, While tapping on `Searchbar` `textField`  I want to be set **Date picker  as inputView**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
```

References for text field : [iPhone display date picker on UITextField touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197855/iphone-display-date-picker-on-uitextfield-touch)
But unable to  able to access Search bar Textfield. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get search textField using following code. Write it in `viewDidLoad`

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = [self.searchController.searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[searchBarTextField setInputView:datePicker];
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Not at all Datepicker will display

Comment: @property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;

Comment: You need to set this line after you have created the search bar programatically

Comment: Please edit your question with your code that you have write for programatically adding search bar

Comment: UISearchController (Search bar) Not available in Storyboard. Need to add in programmatically

Comment: This code only when i added UIdatepicker and UIserachcontroll in ViewdidLoad.

Comment: I hope your happy now .

Answer (score 0):

First set delegate of `UISearchBar` then you can use following delegate method :

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    [self showDatePicker];
    return NO;
}

-(void) showDatePicker {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(showSelectedDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)showSelectedDate:(id)sender {
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.date.inputView;
    searchBar.text = [self formatDate:picker.date];
}
```

You can use any date formatter to show date in desired format.

Comment: - (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar*)searchBar {
    [self showDatePicker];
    return NO; If NO nothink will display. If YES Datepicker and Keyboard both will display
}

Comment: Option 1 : Keep return YES in searchBarShouldBeginEditing and in 'showDatePicker' write [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

Option 2 : Add tap gesture on UISearchBar, write @selector for same. And in that gesture method, call 'showDatePicker' method.
In this case, don't set delegate for UISearchBar. I think this will work.