# how to show date in textfield from date picker?

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

After Clicked...Date is not shown in textfield.
Textfield is in custom cell of tableview.

[image]

Comment: When you hit done, get the date from the pickerView and use NSDateFormatter to format it into the text. Place the resulting text in the textField.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this question. You did not even bother to do preliminary research prior to asking the question. You haven't tried anything at all. You haven't even bothered to mention which language are you using. This is a basic question which has been answered trillions of times, go google it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone display date picker on UITextField touch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197855/iphone-display-date-picker-on-uitextfield-touch)

Comment: Follow this tutorial: http://www.swiftdevcenter.com/uidatepicker-as-input-view-to-uitextfield-swift/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[txtField_date setInputView:datePicker];

-(void) dateTextField:(id)sender
{
UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)txtField_date.inputView;
[picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *eventDate = picker.date;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:eventDate];
txtField_date.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dateString];
}
```

Try this code.

Comment: Where do you get `txtFieldBranchYear.inputView`?

Comment: Also, why are you setting `[picker setMaximumDate:[NSDate date]];` in ValueChangedEvent?  You should set it before displaying your DatePicker

Comment: if you not set the date picker maximum date just forget this line and use this code.

Comment: And as told by the OP, the textfield is in a TableViewCell, so it is unlikely that you would have a property named `txtField_date` to access it. You will first have to access the modelClass used to populate the cell, update it and reload the cell. Or if you like bad designs, you could access the cell and then access its subviews.

Comment: you have to already add the textfield in custom cell in tableview.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the date property on `UIDatePicker` and convert it to `NSString` and set it to your `UITextField`.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];  // set your own format
NSString *formattedDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:yourPicker.date];
textField.text = formattedDateString;
```