# UIDatePicker Shows Empty Picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

`UIDatePicker` Shows Empty Picker View. It's working perfect, I mean It is scrolling, It is setting date to respective textfield but in picker view it is not displaying date. I have attached a screenshot.

Code for DatePiker,

```
 datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
 datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
 [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

 _txtDue.inputView = datePicker;
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I think you forget to set the frame for datepicker

Comment: https://github.com/kiritmodi2702/Custom-DatePicker

Comment: in here its works perfectly

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: Make sure you have clear the color of contents in pickerView.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : As I am setting date picker as textfield's input view, I don't think that it requires to set frame! and there is no additional code related it!

Comment: @Lion - problem is some where else

Comment: Yeah that's i want to find, I know problem is somewhere else. So, I am looking for person who have face same issue, because it is project specific issue, this same code will work in another project. It might be side effect of some third party libraries, but i can't figure out. So, I am just looking for person who has faced same issue! @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Try clearing the derived data of your project?

Comment: @Rikh  : No deleting derived data is not worked!

Comment: Clean build folder, restart Mac/Xcode do the whole cycle of trying everything!

Comment: That i have done already!

Comment: Check this Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11198489/3378413

Comment: @MihirOza : Please check my code in question, I am doing exactly like link mentions!

Comment: have you added `_txtDue.delegate=self;`

Comment: yes, I have set delegate and issue is not that because date picker is scrolling and setting date also to respective textfield, but issue is "It displays blank date picker", read my question! @MihirOza

Comment: I created one demo and it's working for me Please compare your code with this demo. https://github.com/ozamihir1990/MyTabbar.git

Comment: This same code (posted in comment) is working fine in demo(another project if i made), but it is project specific issue, It is happen withing my existing project only! Read above comments!

Comment: I am not sure but may be you missed something in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out it. It was a issue of one third party library called [UIHidingView](https://github.com/yoman07/UIHidingView)!! It was added by someone in this project. This library's description from github states that,

> UIHidingView is an iOS class that displays UIView element on top UITableView which is hiding when Table View is scrolling

Now `UIDatePicker` internally used tableview in it so, it was hiding it's components!

PS : take care when using third party libraries!!